# Who was Dasharatha's second wife?

Tags: ramayana, dasharatha, kaikeyi

Who was Dhasharatha's second wife?
Sumitra or Kaikeyi?
Some tell it is Kaikeyi but others say it is Sumitra. Please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

According to Valmiki Ramayan, Kaikeyi is the second wife of King Dasharatha. In [Aranya Kand](http://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=3&field_sarga_value=16&field_sloka_value=37), when Lakshmana is criticizing Kaikeyi then Sri Rama told to Lakshmana not to use harsh words against our second mother.

> न तेऽम्बा मध्यमा तात गर्हितव्या कथञ्चन।
>   तामेवेक्ष्वाकुनाथस्य भरतस्य कथां कुरु।।3.16.37।।
>
> O dear, Kaikeyi, our second mother, is never to be criticised like that. You may, however, speak more of Bharata, the lord of the Iksvakus.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the 3 Queens are consistently addressed indicates that Sumitra was the second wife of King Dasharatha:

Dasharatha hands over the payasam first to Kaushaya then to Sumitra, then Kaikeyi and again to Sumitra [Valmiki Ramayana 1.16].

Kaushalya, Sumitra and Kaikeyi receive the brides in Ayodhya with the necessary ceremonies [Valmiki Ramayana 1.77.10].

Kaushaya, Sumitra and Kaikeyi touched the feet of Rishi Bharadwaja [Valmiki Ramayana 2.92.15-16]. Bharata introduced them also in that order [Valmiki Ramayana 2.92.22-26].

God Rama inquires with Bharata about the well-being of Kaushalya, Sumitra and Kaikeyi [Valmiki Ramayana 2.100.10].

God Rama tells Lakshmana to return to Ayodhya and offer His respects to mothers Kaikeyi, Sumitra and Kaushalya [Valmiki Ramayana 3.62.17-18].

God Rama tells Vibhishana that He is now eager to visit Ayodhya and meet Bharata, Kaushalya, Sumitra, Kaikeyi, friend Guha and citizens of Ayodhya [Valmiki Ramayana 6.121.19-20].

Kaushalya, Sumitra and Kaikeyi reached Nandigrama [Valmiki Ramayana 6.127.15]. God Rama offered His salutations to Kaushalya, Sumitra and Kaikeyi [Valmiki Ramayana 6.127.48-49].

God Rama offered His salutations to Kaushalya, Sumitra and Kaikeyi [Valmiki Ramayana 6.128.44].

Hearing about God Rama's legend, a person can get his desires; women like Kaushalya, Sumitra and Kaikeyi obtain sons... [Valmiki Ramayana 6.128-110-111].

Now, coming to another verse about Kaikeyi as translated on http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga16/aranya_16_frame.htm:
न ते अम्बा मध्यमा तात गर्हितव्या कथंचन |
ताम् एव इक्ष्वाकु नाथस्य भरतस्य कथाम् कुरु || ३-१६-३७
"taata = oh, dear Lakshmana; madhyamaa ambaa = middle [second, another,] mother; kathamcana = in any way; te na garhitavyaa = by you, not, deplorable; ikSvaaku naathasya bharatasya = Ikshvaku-s, king, Bharata's; taam kathaam eva kuru = those, stories [topics,] alone, you make [you tell.]"
"In any way, dear Lakshmana, you are not supposed to deplore another mother of ours, but you go on telling the topics of Bharata, the king of Ikshvaku-s."

The word मध्यम is middle, but the word used is मध्यमा which is translated as 'womb' in sanskritdictionary.com and learnsanskrit.cc.

Further, sanskritdictionary.com and Sir M. Monier-Williams translate सुमध्यमा as a graceful or slender-waisted woman which is exactly how Kaikeyi is described in Valmikiramayan.net 1.77.10.

[Source: http://valmikiramayan.net; 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani pg 2]